# Fiware Wirecloud Block redirecting to mobile page

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I got a public mashup in my fiware instance. Is it possible to block the redirecting to the mobile site? (I think its not an url, I cant find a redirecting in the logs. Maybe some javascript code?)

And how does fiware/wirecloud determine if I'm using a mobile device or a desktop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WireCloud currently uses the user agent provided by the client to detect if the user is running on a mobile device. This detection is based on [user-agents](https://github.com/selwin/python-user-agents) python module. This mechanism is specific to WireCloud, other FIWARE GEs can use other mechanism.

Finally, currently WireCloud doesn't allow you to disable the use of the mobile version in a general way. You can append a `?mode=classic` to the URL (e.g. `https://mashup.lab.fiware.org/alvaro-arranz-garcia/ckan-valencia?mode=classic`) for forcing the use of the desktop version of WireCloud, but any user not using this modifier will get the mobile version when accessing from a smartphone.

Feel free to create a feature request :-)